# How do you remove rust stains from bathroom sink?

Tags: staining, rust-removal

I have two rust colored stains on my bathroom vanity.  I've tried baking soda & lemon juice, Mr. Clean Eraser, CLR, Lime away, Barkeeper's Friend, etc. with no success.  Any other ideas on how to remove them?

Of note: These were already here when I purchased my home, so I do not know the cause.

[image]

Comment: Is that a porcelain enamel sink, or plastic? Looks more like a dye leaching into plasticizer than a rust stain to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with CLR or vinegar : use plumber's putty to make a ring and make a small pool.  Hydrogen peroxide would be another choice (not concurrently, with ANY of the other choices)

Its location suggests a leaky soap dispenser.

Solid surface materials can be sanded (starting at 220) and then up through the grits (320, 400, 600), finishing with auto body rubbing compound then polishing compound.

Comment: H2O2, or bleach will oxidize some dyes to colorless. Other dyes respond better to being reduced. For that, the Sodium hydrosulfite in Rit Color Remover could well suffice: http://hpd.nlm.nih.gov/cgi-bin/household/brands?tbl=brands&id=16027001  I'd try both possibilities before getting out the sandpaper.

Answer (score 0):

OK you have tried all of the right things.  Now it's time to bring out the big guns...

[The Works](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VM2QBI) - Completely anti-green.  Tons of hydrochloric acid in it - which helps break down rust.

[SOS pads](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009P687K) - You can't use these too much because they can take off the finish coat.

Wear some thick plastic gloves, turn on the fan, pour a little The Works on the rust, let it sit for 5-10 mins, scrub slowly with a lot of pressure with SOS pad.